# Border at Bottom Of Div, no padding or margin

Tags: html, css, image, border

please take a look at this superduper simple pen, maybe someone can tell me where the space in the div under the image is coming from?

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="url">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: indianred;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    img {
        padding-bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/hergi/pen/MQLQRd

thanks in advance, this sh/t is driving me crazy right now :'/

Comment: img float:left can solve your problem but how it comes from is still a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `<img>` is an `display: inline-block` element. You can read https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements to understand it.

For short term, you can add

1. `display: block` to `.parent img`
2. or add `font-size: 0` to `.parent` to fix it.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}

.parent img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-border {    
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: ease all .3s;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  &:hover
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://echtlieb.de/themes/Frontend/Echtlieb/frontend/_public/src/img/produkteigenschaften/frauen/doerte/stoff/stoff-sweat_(grau_meliert).jpg" />
  <div class="hover-border">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, your link explained it very good :)

Comment: @w3debugger, why are you height and width to the div and use 100% of them for the img? This will make all images 500x350, even if they are big. Simply adding 'display: block' to the image should be sufficient as the answer to this question.

Comment: @ivp I didn't modify anything else. I copied her code and just provide the solution she wants. :)

Comment: ok. Cool. My bad then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'display: block;' to the image. No need to provide height and width to the parent div.

```css
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: indianred;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent img {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://echtlieb.de/themes/Frontend/Echtlieb/frontend/_public/src/img/produkteigenschaften/frauen/doerte/stoff/stoff-sweat_(grau_meliert).jpg" />
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin:0px` to body tag, by default it takes some margin.
check updated snippet below..

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: indianred;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent img {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="https://echtlieb.de/themes/Frontend/Echtlieb/frontend/_public/src/img/produkteigenschaften/frauen/doerte/stoff/stoff-sweat_(grau_meliert).jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: this one also has the red line for me oO